# Sequence $x_n \to 0$ for which $f(x_n)$ does not converge to $f(0)$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> Give an example of a sequence $x_n \to 0$ for which $f(x_n)$ does not converge to $f(0)$, when $f(x)=1$, when $x \in \mathbb{Q}$ and $f(x)=0$ when $x \in \mathbb{R}- \mathbb{Q}$.

Would $x_n=\frac1n$ work here? $\frac1n \to 0$ and I have $$f(\frac1n)= \begin{cases} 1, \frac1n \in \Bbb{Q}, \\ 0, \frac1n \in \Bbb{R}-\Bbb{Q} \end{cases}$$ I'm not sure this works?

Answer (score 1):

No it does not work.

Notice that $\frac 1n\in \mathbb Q$ always, so $f(x_n)=1$.

Also $0\in\mathbb Q$ so $f(0)=1$ and the continuity relation stands.

You need $f(x_n)=0$ eventually when $n\gg 1$ to make it fail.

For that you need $x_n\in\mathbb R-\mathbb Q$ eventually when $n$ is large, to simplify we can take $x_n$ always irrational.

For instance $x_n=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{n}$ would work.